# How do I map relationships in Custom NSManagedObject class

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, xcode5

I have two entities: Farmer, Livestock. a farmer has a one-to-many relationship with livestocks. So that each farmer may have a name, address, userid, pig set, chicken set, cow set.

I need to create a custom managed object class for farmer as

```
@interface ManagedFarmer : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *date;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *address;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *userid;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *cows;//? set of cows: relationship to Livestock entity, designated cows

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *chickens;//? 1-to-many relationship to Livestock entity, designated as chickens: 
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *pigs;
```

- is NSArray the correct way to represent the relationship data?
- when I fetch a farmer by userid, does cascading automatically occur such that I also get all the Livestock entities belonging to this farmer for free?

Comment: Click Coredata file .xcdatamodald and down there you can see editor style, cilck on modal icon and you'll find you tables over there. Then create desired relations among the tables and then create NSManagedObject classes.Its done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### "NSArray the correct way to represent the relationship data?"

`NSSet` is used to model relationships in an `NSManagedObject` subclass. `NSArray` is used for fetched properties, which are a kind of weak relationship.

Typically you would use the [Core Data Model Editor built into Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-core_data_modeling_tool/Articles/about_cd_modeling_tool.html) to modify your model, and then have Xcode generate the `NSManagedObject` subclass files as a template for you to work with. This would automatically generate `NSSet` properties for relationships (but, sadly, [will not automatically generate properties for fetched properties](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5232274786222080) ).

#### "when I fetch a farmer by userid, does cascading automatically occur such that I also get all the Livestock entities belonging to this farmer for free?"

When objects are fetched their relationships are "faults". The object graph will only have placeholders for the objects at the target of the relationship until they are accessed. This helps limit the size of the in-memory object graph, and is something that Core Data is very good at. You can choose to include the targets of relationships in a fetch by setting the appropriate relationship key paths for fetching on your fetch request using `setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:`.

Answer (score 1):

So a NSManagedObject is used in conjunction with Core Data. Create your model, create the relationships in that model and then have Xcode create your NSManagedObject classes for you.

Answer (score 0):

The following link has a basic tutorial for doing what you are asking: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-subclassing-nsmanagedobject--cms-21880